# Getting error CSRF Token mismatch laravel 7

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am getting CSRF Token mismatch error while I am updating my page. I have included csrf token in both input hidden fields and as well as in ajax call..still getting the same error.

Here is my input

```
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And i have included in my ajax call like this

```
 var sendInfo       = {
        'edit_qtype_id':edit_qtype_id,
        'arr':arr,
        'saveEditQtypeFile':1,
        'qtype_name':qtype_name,
        'qtype_subject_id':qtype_subject_id,
        'qtype_topic_id':qtype_topic_id,
        'qtype_option':qtype_option,
        '_token' : $('#token').val()
    };
```

Still getting CSRF Token mismatch.

Comment: please read [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token)

Comment: Pls post the code of your ajax call function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the csrf in your blade like this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And then write this line above your AJAX call or at the start of your JS file.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

And finally remove the token from the ajax calls and try.

remove this line `'_token' : $('#token').val()`.